Objects are leaking into unmanaged memory
I am experiencing a very odd behavior as of now that I haven't seen anytime before. I try to find out why our ASP.NET Core app is using so much memory. Looking at Rider's performance monitor you can see there is insanely high unmanaged memory usage.

So when I looked into the source of this with dotMemory and WinDbg I found that I have a whopping ~1GB of strings lying around. So most of the memory used is just strings next to that some model classes.
Thing is: We read deeply nested documents from MongoDB and wrap the entities with proxy model classes that basically make the POCO entities a bit more useful (automatic reference resolving, generating model paths, etc.). So it's not unusual that these models take quite a bit of space in memory. Furthermore we create said model paths which basically determine the exact nested location in the BSON document in order to perform updates on them without a lot of manual search. These model paths generate quite a few strings.
So in total: It's normal that we need a few hundred MBs of RAM. But what I don't get: These are all managed objects. Yet they seem to leak into unmanaged memory where they just can't be collected. Or at least they get collected very infrequently and slowly which causes our Clusters to scale up since memory quickly exceeds the limits on productive environments.
Since we use a custom BsonSerializer for one of our entities I have to assume that MongoDB is doing some unmanaged work and since the whole BSON serializer logic invokes creation of these models and paths they somehow land in the unmanaged space. But still I can't really make up how that would happen. It seems to be the case though since all these models and stuff would probably exceed the ~50MB managed memory you can see during the whole time. So these objects somehow seem to leak out into unmanaged space?
And even if that's the case: How do I avoid that?

Could you please reupload the image? It seems that the URL is broken.

"So when I looked into the source of this with dotMemory and WinDbg I found that I have a whopping ~1GB of strings lying around" - nothing unusual. Depending on your hardware, GC settings and .NET code you can easily have 3x more allocated memory that doesn't get collected. What is interesting is how you managed to connect your statements "Looking at Rider's performance monitor you can see there is insanely high unmanaged memory usage" and "Yet they seem to leak into unmanaged memory where they just can't be collected" with those strings.

Your observation "Or at least they get collected very infrequently and slowly..." is correct and the reason might be because "all these models and stuff would probably exceed the ~50MB managed memory". In this case the memory doesn't leak but your objects are allocated on LOH (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) that has different collection and compaction procedures that typical Gen 0/1/2. Furthermore, memory will increase constantly even if LOH is cleared but not compacted (when .NET can't fit new objects into freed memory "holes")

Can you please also add to the post the following details: hardware where this app runs, if the app is containerized (if yes, what resources does it use), GC configuration, an average document size in bytes.
